# MessageApi.MessageListener in Wear Activity Not Triggering

Tags: android, google-play-services, wear-os

So I've looked around on StackOverflow and haven't found an answer, so I'm wondering if there's just something I'm missing. I have an activity in the 'wear' portion of my app with the same package and application name as my mobile part, but it isn't being triggered when a message is sent:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements MessageApi.MessageListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks {

private GoogleApiClient mApiClient;
private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;

private ListView mListView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>( this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 );
    mListView.setAdapter( mAdapter );

    initGoogleApiClient();
}

private void initGoogleApiClient() {
    mApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder( this )
            .addApi(Wearable.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .build();

    if( mApiClient != null && !( mApiClient.isConnected() || mApiClient.isConnecting() ) )
        mApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if( mApiClient != null && !( mApiClient.isConnected() || mApiClient.isConnecting() ) )
        mApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {
    mAdapter.add( new String( messageEvent.getData() ) );
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    Toast.makeText( this, "Wear onMessageReceived", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Toast.makeText( this, "Wear onConnected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
    Wearable.MessageApi.addListener( mApiClient, this );
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if( mApiClient != null && mApiClient.isConnected() ) {
        mApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}
```

From my mobile activity, I send a message that I would expect would be picked up from the Wear activity. If I use a WearListenerService, then onMessageReceived is triggered fine, I just can't get it to hit in an activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private GoogleApiClient mApiClient;

private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;

private ListView mListView;
private EditText mEditText;
private Button mSendButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    init();
    initGoogleApiClient();
}

private void initGoogleApiClient() {
    mApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder( this )
            .addApi( Wearable.API )
            .build();

    mApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mApiClient.disconnect();
}

private void init() {
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.list_view );
    mEditText = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.input );
    mSendButton = (Button) findViewById( R.id.btn_send );

    mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>( this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 );
    mListView.setAdapter( mAdapter );

    mSendButton.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String text = mEditText.getText().toString();
            if( !TextUtils.isEmpty( text ) ) {
                mAdapter.add( text );
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                sendMessage( text );
            }
        }
    });
}

private void sendMessage( final String text ) {
    new Thread( new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult nodes = Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes( mApiClient ).await();
            for(Node node : nodes.getNodes()) {
                Log.e("MainActivity", "node id: " + node.getId() );
                MessageApi.SendMessageResult result = Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(
                        mApiClient, node.getId(), text, null).await();
            }

            runOnUiThread( new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mEditText.setText( "" );
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Anyone have any suggestions on what I may be missing? I can fall back to using a service, but I want to try and get this working with an activity if I can.

Thanks!

Comment: try to insert a callback in your sendMessage to check if the message is sent or not.

Comment: Same here, seems like the only solution is to use a broadcast event, but what's the point to have a MessageListener for the views where there is no events sending through, weird stuff!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out onMessageReceived is running on its own thread, not the UI thread, so you have to wrap the toast message and any of your own UI code in runOnUiThread.

Comment: I have no any UI code in onMessageReceived and it's never trigerred :(. (WearableListenerService work fine). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in your Wear Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy()");

    if(mApiClient != null) 
        mApiClient.unregisterConnectionCallbacks(this);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

And adding this to the start of your onStop():

```
    if (mApiClient != null) {
        Wearable.MessageApi.removeListener(mApiClient, this);
```

Then reboot your watch, and re-test.  Otherwise a previous instance of your activity will have registered the listeners, possibly confusing matters.

Comment: Thanks, but still no luck. The wear device does connect to play services, and the message is sent successfully, I'm just not getting anything on the Wear side: 09-23 08:23:12.888  31953-32259/? E/MainActivity﹕ node id: a6b05ffc-4c93-401b-aae8-6c04e84b9ea0
09-23 08:23:12.898  31953-32259/? E/MainActivity﹕ Message sent successfully

Comment: Similar error here. Have you managed to resolve this issue somehow? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No, this doesn't work. The message only gets hit to the class which extended WearableListenerService.

Comment: Exact same ptoblem here. WearableListenerService works, MessageListener doesn't. I'm losing it here

Comment: The same problem (

Answer (score 0):

Check signingConfigs in build.gradle, for me the problem was that I used different signing keys.